# What was the effect of the fall of the Soviet Union on African economies?

Tags: economy, africa, soviet-union

In a speech about Aleksandr Solzhenitsyn, Jordan Peterson claims that the fall of the Soviet Union had a very good effect on Africa, he claims that African economies are booming like mad now and that happens in part because they don't have the USSR guidance anymore.

My question is if there are any materials that support or confirm this point of view.

[Conversations with John Anderson: Jordan Peterson and Dave Rubin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVYDdZWUWlE)
(min 27-28)

Comment: It's trivial to find GDP data. What's less than trivial is to work out what was due to the collapse of the Soviet Union, considering the conflicts between crony capitalism, communism, and radical Islam. If it maybe brought an end to the Ethiopian Civil War, did it help cause the Congo Wars (1996-2003) and associated economic collapse in the DRC and wider  region? Likewise, after 1990 western governments no longer saw any point in supporting apartheid South Africa as a bulwark against communism, possibly leading to peace and prosperity in the region, or the contrary. But who knows?

Comment: Africa is 1.2 billion people in 54 different countries, which all got affected in different ways by the fall of the Soviet Union. Some in positive ways, some in negative ways, others not at all. So this question might be a lot broader than you think. And I am also not sure if it would perhaps fit better on https://history.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Philipp it is possible to find economic statistics for the whole of Africa, as can be shown by googlin “GDP of Africa.” You make a good point about maybe moving this to [history.se] though.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica That would be as useful as an economic statistic for the whole of Asia, which would throw India, the whole Middle East, parts of Russia, China, Japan, North Korea, South Korea and several other countries together which really don't have much to do with each other. Africa is a continent which is a lot more diverse than many people give it credit for. Trying to handle "Africa" as a single monolithic entity is a gross oversimplification which hides a lot of important complexities of the reality.

Comment: I don't see the big point in claiming "Africa" can't be discussed here due to its undeniable diversity.  Replace "Africa" with "Europe" and that would seem like a reasonable enough question to me, allowing some broad stroke answers.  Thing is the fall of USSR probably also meant less CIA meddling and as we saw in Central America that meddling was generally not benign in nature.

Comment: Is it possible to move the question to History SE or I have to copy the question there?